# Is WeifenLuo DockPanel Suite applicable to an MDI environment only?

Tags: c#, winforms, dockpanel-suite

My point is - as I see in WeifenLuo DockPanel suite samples - there is used only MDI environment.

But if I want to use docking inside of a child-form, can I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the sample application you will see one of the docking modes available is `DockingWindow`. This mode does not use the built-in Windows concept of MDI.

To have multiple levels of docking you can use a `DockPanel` on each of the child documents in the main panel, this is entirely allowed.

Due to OS limitations, you may experience issues with resizing in these multi level scenarios. If so, enable the `SupportDeeplyNestedContent` property on the `DockPanel`.